# Ionic 5 + cordova-background-geolocation-lt: iOS App Terminates, delay in awakening the background service

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, background, ionic4

We're using Ionic 5 with cordova-background-geolocation-lt service to receive background locations. On the 'location' event, we collect location information and push it to our real-time database on Firebase. What happens is, on iOS, when we run on simulator everything works perfectly fine. But when we use the build on actual phone and kill/terminate the app, background location does not work. After several hours, it comes alive and works fine then. Why is it taking so long for the background service to come back alive?

P.S. It's not the 200m barrier issue as we tested it on highway for 2 hours going 100km/h.